# How would I replace multiple strings found with preg_match with a MD5 version?

Tags: php, regex

I am able to find and replace, but I want to replace the current context with a MD5 hashed version of itself.

```
    $feed = preg_replace('/(<photo>.+?)+(<\/photo>)/i', '<photo>http://colorvisiontesting.com/plate%20with%205.jpg</photo>', $feed);
```

That replaces the occurrence, but I need to also get it's content. So in this case, I want to take the contents of the  node and replace it inline with a md5($photocontents) version of itself.

I have about 200 occurrences in this string that need to be found and replaced.

preg_match_all will find them and put them in an array (does not help) and preg_replace does not give me the content of the regex match.

For example:

```
<photo>img.jpg</photo>
```

needs to be replaced with

```
<photo>43534e3242er234.jpg</photo>
```

Obviously that is a random string but I need to replace the node with the md5 hashed version of itself. –

Thanks!

Comment: Whats the concrete problem? You can find and you can replace, so I dont see one ^^

Comment: Your question is very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `preg_replace_callback()` or `preg_replace()` with the 'e' modifier as suggested by Hosh Sadiq. Here is a tested code snippet which uses the second approach.

```php
$feed = preg_replace('%(<photo[^>]*>)(.+?)(\.jpg</photo>)%ise',
    '"$1". md5("$2") ."$3";', $feed);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$feed = preg_replace('#\<photo\>(.*?)\.jpg\<\/photo\>#is', '<photo>'.md5('\\1').'.jpg</photo>', $feed);
```

edit

```
$feed = '<photo>hello.jpg</photo> <photo>world.jpg</photo>'; 

function replace($matches){
    return '<photo>'.md5($matches[1]).'.jpg</photo>';
}

$feed = preg_replace_callback('#<photo>(.*?).jpg</photo>#is', 'replace', $feed);

echo $feed; //<photo>5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592.jpg</photo> <photo>7d793037a0760186574b0282f2f435e7.jpg</photo>
```

Comment: For example: <photo>img.jpg</photo> needs to be replaced with <photo>43534e3242er234.jpg</photo> - obviously that is a random string but I need to replace the node with the md5 hashed version of itself.

Comment: This does not work. The MD5 value substituted for each and every photo will be `'b5101eb6e685091719013d1a75756a53'` which is the MD5 hash for the literal string: `'\\1'`

Comment: @ridgerunner, you are right, I edited question couple of times because I wasn't sure what OP asked. Your question should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php preg_replace('/yourRegex/e', 'md5(\'\\1\')', $subject); ?>
```

notice the e modifier after the / delimeter.. this tells it to evaluate...